# PHP Email To DB class

Tags: php, database, email

I'm using the [Class following this link](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3324-PHP-Retrieve-e-mail-messages-into-a-MySQL-database.html) to retrieve Email data from the Server to `mysql db`.

This works perfect when I use without modifying it. 
It deletes all the Emails from the server. But I need to just get a copy to database without deleting it.

for that, I commented following lines.

```
$this->email_delete();
$this->email_expunge();
```

Now what happens is that script download only oldest message from inbox repeatedly and it won't stop. Please help. I need to get a copy to database without deleting then from the server.

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer but I think you should not use this class. It has some serious issues (it uses mysql_query, it uses addslashes to "protect" SQL injection, it's not maintained for 8 years...) so it's dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Do u know any other solution similar to this...